# Need some help opening excel files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Just having a strange issue. I am new in python and while running the below code. Geetting error. I have tried google but unable to run my code. Any advise please

```
import openpyxl
import os

os.chdir('/Users/omer/Documents/Python_Code/Udemy/Excel_Word_Pdf/')
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

workbook.get_sheet_names()

cell = sheet['A1']
```

And the error i amgetting is

```
lesson42.py:13: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
  sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
lesson42.py:15: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).
  workbook.get_sheet_names()
```

Comment: Instead of sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
can you try sheet = workbook['Sheet1']

Comment: It doesnot work . Tried it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the following. This should work.

```
import openpyxl
import os

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet = workbook['Sheet1']

print(workbook.sheetnames)

cell = sheet['A1'].value
print(cell)
```

Answer (score 0):

DeprecationWarning means that you're calling a function that's no longer supported. Go through their documentation to find the new function that's used to get_name, or try using pandas

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing sheetnames first: `workbook.sheetnames`

This will give you a list of available sheets, then you can call them with `workbook[#Some Sheet]`